# Google Webmaster Tools "Incomplete microdata with schema.org" error for rich snippets

Tags: opencart, microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I have problem with rich snippets in google webmaster tools when I try to test the link - > http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjimfish.de%2Fabu-garcia-revo-stx-l-lh-multirolle&html=" 
I receive the error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org" but don't understand what I forgot and can't see the rating star and price like this http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.brandedmall.com%2Fasus-a45vm-3rd-gen-intel-core-i7-3610qm-gt630m-15-quot-a-series-notebook&html=. 
I use the cms opencart with vQmod.

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturer expected type is Person or Organization, not text.